# How to copy different tables of different sizes from one known sheet to another in Excel Macros using the header of the table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a csv file opened in a sheet named as "data" which has a lot of tables. The only linking factor to search for the req'd table is that header of the table starts with `sales_` e.g `sales_1`, `sales_1985` etc. The size of the table varies sometimes; and I need to sort and import these tables with 'the click of a button'!! I have got myself till the point I could sort the headers starting with `sales_` but when i try to import these tables, I get an error 1004(attached). The code so far is also attached, could some one help please?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim FirstAddress1 As String
    Dim debt As Variant
    Dim growth As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim Rcount1 As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim NewSh As Worksheet
    Dim Newsh1 As Worksheet
    Dim row As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Fill in the search Value
    debt = Array("Sales*Debt*_GMAP", "Sales*Growth*_GMAP")

    Set NewSh = Sheets("debtshow")
    Set Newsh1 = Sheets("tables")

    With Sheets("data").Range("A1:Z3000")

        Rcount = 0
        row = 0

        For I = LBound(debt) To UBound(debt)

            Set Rng = .Find(What:=debt(I), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Do
                    row = Rng.row + 3

                    Rcount = Rcount + 1
' I know I am doing something wrong here to copy the row(for starters, and then table) but I dont understand what!

                   Sheets("data").Range("row:row").Copy Newsh1.Range("2:2" & Rcount)
                    Rng.Copy NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount)

                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        Next I
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your data looks something like this:

```
sales_1    Data1      Data2      Data3
info1      info2      info3      info4
info5      info6      info7      info8
<blank>    <blank>    <blank>    <blank>
sales_2    Data1      Data2      Data3
info9      info10     info11     info12
info13     info14     info15     info16
<blank>    <blank>    <blank>    <blank>
```

**Based on that assumption** I would suggest turning each group of data `Sales_1`, `Sales_2`, etc. into a table so you can reference them more easily later, something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim FirstAddress As String
    'Dim debt As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim NewSh As Worksheet
    Dim Newsh1 As Worksheet
    Dim row As String

'leave this out until it's all working - it'll just frustrate you
'With Application
'    .ScreenUpdating = False
'    .EnableEvents = False
'End With

    'Fill in the search Value
    debt = Array("Sales*Debt*_GMAP", "Sales*Growth*_GMAP")

    Set NewSh = Sheets("debtshow")
    Set Newsh1 = Sheets("tables")

    With Sheets("data").UsedRange 'use this instead of hard coding your data range 
                                  'provides room for growth
    set rng = .find(What:="sales_", LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    while not rng is nothing then
      FirstAddress = Rng.Address
      set rng1 = .find(What:=Debt(I), LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlPart, _
                    'this should get you the row you just found in the previous search
                    after:=.rows(rng.rows(1)), _ 
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
      if rng1 is nothing then
        row = .rows.count 'we've found the last one, run to the end
      else
        row = rng1.rows(1) - 2 'store the last row of the block of data
      end if

'now, make a table out of the data we found
'make the table name "sales_x" based on the cell we found
      .listobjects.add(xlSrcRange, .range(cells(rng.rows(1), .columns.count), cells(row, .columns.count), , xlYes).Name = rng.cells(1,1)

'at this point, you can use .ListObjects to copy this block of data somewhere
'or, you can leave the data as tables, then loop through later and copy them
'to where ever you need them
      rng = rng1 'we've already found where the next block of data starts so use it
    wend 

'With Application
'    .ScreenUpdating = False
'    .EnableEvents = True
'End With
End Sub
```

I am, however, confused by the `Debt` array you're creating and why you're searching for those values in the formulas (`LookIn:=xlFormula`), since that didn't seem to be any part of your text description of the problem. This code ignores that and searches for `Sales_x` as you described. If you need to search for `Debt()`, then you'll need to modify the `.Find()` statements appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for considering to answer. The table is more like this. Sales_VolumeGear2debt4WD_GMAP        
       
        
 jan feb mar apr may june july 4000
0 info1 info2 info3 info4 info5 info6 info7 info8
0 info1 info2 info3 info4 info5 info6 info7 info8
0 info1 info2 info3 info4 info5 info6 info7 info8
10 info1 info2 info3 info4 info5 info6 info7 info8

I tried to run your code, the .listobjects line is returning a syntax error, and I dint know why.. you are right, i needn't run the lookin:xlformula but i was trying not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Sadly, that's unreadable in the comment, add it to your original question.

Comment: Also, describe the error `.ListObjects()` is returning.

Comment: sorry about that, the formatting dint go well. the table is more like what you have mentioned, but the header of the table is actually 3 rows above the table in the beginning column (if the table begins at A then A). in your code, i changed the "while not rng is nothing then" to "IF", i hope it is what you intended. but I got stuck in .listobject line as VB returned a syntax error.

Comment: Since you're changing code, why don't you update the original post with your data layout and with the exact code you're now running. That will make it much easier to understand what's going on. (be sure to add it to the end, don't replace what you've already got there.)